# How to create a input popup in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, validation, input, xamarin.android, dialog

Looking to create a popup where the user must type 'CONFIRM' to continue. I know how to develop a popup with 'CONTINUE' or 'CANCEL' on it but unsure of how to implement one that checks/validates the users input.
Using native Xamarin on Android with C#.

This is what I have so far. I just need some way of comparing what the user has input to the word CONFIRM

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
ad.setTitle ("Type text");
ad.setView(et); // <----
ad.show();
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-user-input-dialog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a layout with EditText named `CustomDialog.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText_Name"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code in MainActivity.cs OnCreate method.

```
   var editText = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomDialog, null);

        var ad = (new AlertDialog.Builder(this)).Create();
        ad.SetTitle("Type text");
        ad.SetView(editText); // <----
        ad.SetButton("Confirm", ConfirmButton);
        ad.Show();
```

The code of ConfirmButton.

```
 void ConfirmButton(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = (AlertDialog)sender;
        var username = (EditText)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText_Name);
        var name = username.Text;
        if (name=="hello")
        {

        }
    }
```

You could get the text of EditText now.

[image]

**Updated:**

In Xamarin.forms, when you want to display a prompt, you could use `DisplayPromptAsync`.

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        PopUp();
    }
    public async void PopUp()
    {
        string s = await DisplayPromptAsync("Pop up Window", "Type text:", "Confirm", keyboard: Keyboard.Text);
        if (s == "hello")
        {
           //do something here...
        }
    }
```

[image]

Display Pop-ups: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer to my question. One question though, I am using xamarin Android and so I can't use CustomDialog, is there an equivalent that I could use?